# Do I need @types/ before every dependency in react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, react-native

I would like to convert my existing react native app to `typescript`.

The documentation says to uninstall existing dependencies and replace them with something like this:

`yarn add --dev @types/jest @types/react @types/react-native @types/react-test-renderer`

Do I need to do this with *every* dependency? What if some dependencies don't have `@types/` ?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactnative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "formik": "^0.11.11",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "native-base": "^2.7.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-autogrow-textinput": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-input": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.0.0-rc.3",
    "react-native-material-color": "^1.0.15",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "0.0.20",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.5.5",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.1.6",
    "recompose": "^0.27.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "yup": "^0.25.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The documentation says to uninstall existing dependencies and replace them

Actually you have to install both the package, such as `react` and the related types as `@types/react`. If `react` is already installed, you don't have to uninstall and reinstall.

> Do I need to do this with every dependency?

As long as you want types for it.

> What if some dependencies don't have @types/ ?

Then you either type it on your own, or you type it as `any` and you don't have the typesafety of Typescript anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No, packages that start with `@types/` are TypeScript *definitions*. They should be installed *in addition* to the actual packages if these don't already ship with TS definitions (many large/popular libraries do). Your editor and the TypeScript compiler will use the definitions to perform type checking.

Answer (score 0):

`@types` typings exist for all popular libraries. Some libraries include typings (.d.ts files), no typings are needed for them, the example is `axios`.

For libraries that don't have typings, a developer can provide own type declarations or use untyped imports, e.g. with `require`. The example is [open issue](https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet/issues/55) for `react-native-actionsheet`.

> The documentation says to uninstall existing dependencies

The documentation shouldn't say anything like that. Existing dependencies shouldn't be uninstalled. Only respective `@type` dependencies should be added.